# Adding class to nested img

Tags: javascript

Super simple representation of my code:

```
 <div class = "parent_class">
  <a href="#"> 
    <img src="something.jpg">
  </a>
 </div>
```

I need to add a class to the `img`, but this is proving difficult (for me). Is there a simple way to do this in javascript? I know I have the option of `:first-child`, but I don't think that applies here.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: You want to style the image or you want to add a class name to the element? In what situation? Eg: when the user moves the cursor above the link? Or at specific programmatic event?:

Comment: @slider I could use jQuery.

Comment: @ZorgoZ This is part of a more complicated Wordpress module. For some reason, it doesn't add class to images, so I'm unable to do anything with those images because they don't have a class. I'm looking to put something in my WP functions file to fix this.

Comment: Will you have different classes for different images? If not, you could just apply the same style to all `<img>` tags...

Comment: No...can't apply to all images unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example in plain JS (**without jQuery**):

```
// first you would like to get reference to the parent
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent_class');

// then you get reference to the img nested under parent
const img = parent.querySelector('img'); // this will return reference to the first child img of the parent element

img.classList.add('your-class-goes-here'); // add the class to the element
```

Insert this solution to a function that gets executed in some context (i.e. button click, or 'DOMContentLoad' event).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can access the `img` element with `.parent_class img` [(ancestor > descendent)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) and then use [`addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add a custom class:

```js
$('.parent_class img').addClass('myclass');
```

```css
.myclass {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent_class">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vanilla JS solution:

```js
addclass = function() {
  var e = document.querySelectorAll('.parent_class img')[0];
  e.classList.add("my");
}
```

```css
.my {
 border: 3px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent_class">
  <a href="#"> 
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/30/30">
  </a>
 </div>
  
<button onclick="addclass();">Add class</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery ([Get Started](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)) and use the `addClass()` method ([addClass() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp)).

Comment: Right...but how do I add it specifically just to those images?